# How to define multiple routes in single array

Tags: node.js, routes, restify

I have two different versions of my Api v1 and v2.There is two different folder of both version. And i am call all routes file of both versions separately in my routes.js like this:

```
 module.exports = function (server) {
    const v1Path = "v1";
    const v2Path = "v2";
//v1 files
    require("./"+v1Path+"/routes/a")(server);
    require("./"+v1Path+"/routes/b")(server);
    require("./"+v1Path+"/routes/c")(server);
//v2 files
    require("./"+v2Path+"/routes/a")(server);
    require("./"+v2Path+"/routes/b")(server);
    require("./"+v2Path+"/routes/c")(server);
    require("./"+v2Path+"/routes/d")(server);

};
```

I am calling routes.js file in my server.js like this:

```
var routes = require('./routes')(server);
```

Now my question is, how could i create an array which contains both v1 and v2. and routes all files in a single loop. please help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
module.exports = function (server) {
    const versions = {
       'v1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
       'v2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    };

    Object.keys(versions).forEach(function(version){
        versions[version].forEach(function(route){
            require('./' + version + '/routes/' + route)(server);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: it will through error dude.
Error: Cannot find module './v$({version})/routes/$({route})'
actually when i do some changes it will through that $ is not define. what to do now? and thanks for your answer. @Ezra

Comment: i'm guessing you're running an older version of node without [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). i've edited the answer to reflect that. i'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish other than mounting the routes dynamically.

Comment: dude will you please check my question again. i am changed it. actually it's my mistake. version2 has one new route. your answer is working for it but it just take 1 from versions array. how could i skip index[0] from array? please help me. actually i was try but its not working.

Comment: thanks buddy. it will work. if i have any query surely contact you bro.